# Razor behaving diffrent on live server then test server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hello i am currently developing a ASP.NET MVC 3 application that uses the new razor view engien.
But i am having some problem that dose not accrue when i test the homepage in Visual Studio 2010.

Example one of my pages have the following code

```
Line 37:     <div class="info">
Line 38:         <a href="@LinkHelper.DisplayProfileUrl((int)Model.Album.User.Id, Model.Album.User.Username)">@Model.Album.User.Username</a>
Line 39:         @if (UserHelper.IsModeratorOrAdministrator(Model.Album.UserId)) { <text>(<a href="@LinkHelper.AlbumEditUrl(Model.Album)">Manage Album</a>)</text>}
Line 40:     </div>
```

Give the following error on line 39

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Now in Visual Studio 2010, dose this error not accrue, even with the same data. i have even tryed putting a (int) in front of Model.Album.UserId
I do not understand why i am having this error, or how to fix it.

Call stack:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12630485
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +224
   Cosplay.Helpers.UserHelper.GetUserId() in C:\CosplayTFS\Website\Branches\Albums\Cosplay\Helpers\UserHelper.cs:50
   Cosplay.Helpers.UserHelper.IsModeratorOrAdministrator(Int32 userId) in C:\CosplayTFS\Website\Branches\Albums\Cosplay\Helpers\UserHelper.cs:36
   ASP.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Execute>b__4() in c:\Server\Web\Kasper\test.cosplay.dk\Views\Albums\AlbumDetails.cshtml:39
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClassb.<RenderSection>b__9(TextWriter tw) +289
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +89
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Server\Web\Kasper\test.cosplay.dk\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:61
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +173
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +89
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +234
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +234
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +784900
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +784976
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +453
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371
```

The functions

```
public static bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
    public static bool IsModeratorOrAdministrator(int userId)
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticated())
            return false;
        return GetUserId() == userId || (Roles.IsUserInRole("Moderator") || Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"));
    }
public static int GetUserId()
{
    int tryp;
    if(!int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, out tryp))
        return -1;
    return tryp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that it isn't a problem with the view engine. Given the `System.FormatException`, I would double check the values for either the `Model.Album.UserId` argument for the `IsModeratorOrAdministrator` method, or the `Model.Album` argument for the `AlbumEditUrl` method.

Comment: Yes i have been thinking this aswell, but i was not able to find the problem, i have added the functions to the first post

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  It does appear that it's being thrown in `GetUserId()`, but the `int.TryParse` should be specifically avoiding that exact exception.  Is it possible that the `int.TryParse` was recently changed from `int.Parse`, and there's an older version of the code up on the live server?  It's the only thing I can think of.  Incidentally, is it very common for your system to have `User.Identity.Name` be an integer?  That seems unusual to me.  Just curious.

Comment: Yes the core was int.Parse before, but i change it to the int.TryParse, but the problem is still there, i just use the User.Identity.Name to hold my userId instead of Username

Comment: That must the issue.  If you're certain the newer code is on the live servers, I would try recycling the app pool to see if that does the trick.  This sounds like a frustrating problem, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess... you have different web.configs between the two and the one on the server hasn't registered the namespace in which UserHelper and/or LinkHelper is defined.